# Is there any SQL query or OIM API to get justification entered while disabling user?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, identity, oim

I am looking for justification details for the one user who was disabled manually in OIM and Justification is entered in there while disabling. But since this is done via admin user there is no request generated as such. Still there would be some table which would be storing non request based information.

In nutshell I need justification for disabled user where request is not in system either with OIM Api or SQL anyways

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish something like this is entirely dependent on the approval workflow.

If the workflow is set to NO_WORKFLOW for Admins,  then you should be able to find it on the REQUEST table in the REQUEST_JUSTIFICATION column.

Comment: Your answer is correct for the request level information but in my case since request is not getting generated no workflow would come into picture.

Comment: This should be also true for things that would typically be requests - but their request types are set to be a NO_WORKFLOW situation.  Try doing a search where REQUEST_MODEL_NAME = 'Disable User' or request_isdirect = 1

Comment: since request is not generated the justification entered is not getting saved. Unless there is a request workflow will not triggered even if its NO_WORKFLOW configured.

Comment: This may be a difference in versioning then.  When i tested this going Manage->Users->User Details:->Disable Button  I got a form to enter a justification and when submitted it was documented in the REQUEST table.  The workflow rule for Disable User is requestor.adminRoles equal OrclOIMSystemAdministrator then workflow equal NO_WORFLOW

Comment: are you logging in with admin privileges or non admin?

Comment: with admin privileges